# Python socket.recv in Loop Only Receiving Once

Tags: python, sockets, http, networking

**What I'm Doing:** I have client.recv(4096) after sending a get request via client.send(req) in a loop, where client is a socket already connected to the server.

**What I Want It To Do:** In essence, I just want to see if the file being tested on each iteration of the loop exists on the server or not.

**What It Is Doing:** The loop only gets a response on its first iteration.

**Backstory & Other Info:** I am trying to automate the solving of a hacking challenge I have already beaten. Below is my code, which I have commented on as best as I can. I am using PyPy. Please feel free to ask questions about anything I forgot to mention or was unclear about.

**What I Have Tried:** I have tried: using more complex while loops to attempt to gather all the data being received, searching stackoverflow, a little bit of confused reading on non-blocking sockets.

**Possible Alternative Routes:** Would the requests library help me here better than sockets are?

**My Script:**

```
# I need socket obviously, and I am using time as a method to slow the process down just to wait for the server
import socket
import time

# My dictionaries of things to try ('pre' is not yet integrated)
exts = ['conf', 'bak', 'swp', 'txt', 'old', 'tar', 'gz', 'bz2', 'zip']
pre = ['old', 'bak', 'backup', 'copyof']

# Create and connect the socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("challenge01.root-me.org", 80))

# Send a test request
client.send("HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: challenge01.root-me.org\r\n\r\n")
resp = client.recv(4096)

# Tell myself it's working
if "200" in resp:
    print "[i] Connection is working."

# Setting up my request for the loop
head = "GET /realiste/ch1/login.php"
http = " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: challenge01.root-me.org\r\n\r\n"

# Getting my lists to hold the requests and responses ready
urls = []
respers = []

# Saving myself some typing
def store(request, response):
    urls.append(request)
    respers.append(response)

# Here's the main loop. It's looping through my dictionary (techinically a list)
# of extensions.
for ext in exts:

    # It creates a request with each iteration, in essence adding .old or .bak to the file in the request
    req = head + '.' + ext + http

    # Send it off to the server
    client.send(req)

    # So I set my response variable to "" and then start grabbing data
    # If it has data, I put it in my response
    # If it's empty, I move on out of this while loop and back into the main for loop
    # Thing is, I may get a file or a large response. If either happen, I don't want the entire thing.
    # So I set up a little if/else to look for a connection code. As soon as
    # it finds it, it cuts the while loop.
    # To summarize, once it gets the entire response, or once it finds a connection code,
    # it stops the loop.
    resp = ""
    while True:
        currentResp = client.recv(4096)
        if currentResp != "":
            resp += currentResp
            if "200" in resp or "400" in resp or "404" in resp or "502" in resp:
                store(req, resp)
                break
            else:
                continue
        else:
            break

    # Give the server a breather
    time.sleep(0.5)

# Fancy shmancy output
for search in range(0, len(respers)):
    ecx = 1
    if "200" in respers[search]:
        print "[" + str(ecx) + "] " + urls[search].replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
        print "|__ ::: " + respers[search].splitlines()[0]
        print "|"

# Finish.
print "[*] Done."
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Requests fixes this issue. Adjusted code would be:

```
import requests
import time

exts = ['conf', 'bak', 'swp', 'txt', 'old', 'tar', 'gz', 'bz2', 'zip']
pre = ['old', 'bak', 'backup', 'copyof']

session = requests.head("http://challenge01.root-me.org/")
if session.status_code == 200:
    print "[i] Connection is working."

http = "http://challenge01.root-me.org"
file = "/realiste/ch1/login.php"
urls = []
codes = []

def store(request, code):
    urls.append(request)
    codes.append(code)

for ext in exts:
    req = http + file + "." + ext
    connection = requests.head(req)
    store(req, connection.status_code)
    time.sleep(0.1)

for search in range(0, len(codes)):
    ecx = 1
    if codes[search] != 404:
        print "============="
        print "[" + str(ecx) + "] URL ::: " + urls[search].replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
        print "|__ COD ::: " + str(codes[search])

print "============="
print "[*] Done."
```